# JQueryUI AutoComplete Filtering

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a JQueryUI AutoComplete in my application that allows a User to search for other users in the system. This is actually handled by a JavaScript array loaded in the client during form load. However, I am being told now that, by default, users should only search for other users in the same site they are in. Then, optionally, they can expand that search for users company-wide.

I have come up with a few ways to handle this .. all of which are pretty kludgy. Is there a "right way" to do this before I go down that road?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, You can filter your data using request object & response event in source option. Its up to you how you want to customize but this will get you started..

[jQuery Autocomplete API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) < Look up response & request usage.

```
$('#controlID').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        // add your data manipulation logic here...
    }
});
```

Also, you can access the current user input using 'request.term'

Comment: But can I change that on the fly or is it set initially?

Comment: On the fly. source option runs as you type in the box.

Comment: Its always a good idea to create your data list / array outside of autocomplete implementation to avoid multiple requests to your database.

Comment: You can also refer to my blog here to get some ideas. http://amandeep1986.blogspot.com/2015/02/jquery-auto-complete-tutorial.html

Comment: @Jonhy Thank you .. your blog is very helpful as well. Marked as answered

Comment: Very welcome, feel free to reach out if you're stuck somewhere. Cheers